# Margin Geometry

Tags: spacing

I'm using geometry in my preambule like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50 cm, columnsep=0.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{array, longtable, booktabs, makecell}  
\usepackage{ltablex}  
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\usepackage{stfloats}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{hyphenat}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}  
\usepackage{abstract}
```

and my paragraph spacing is different in several paragraph.
Then, I remove the `bottom=2.50 cm` adjustment.
It seems to resolve my different space of paragraph.

Is this the right way to control vertical space in the text paragraph?

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. That way others can test exactly the same test doc as you are testing and does not have to guess what you are doing. That way you are much much more likely to get help. So help us help you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm using bottom=2.50cm without space. Problem solved since then.